# Цикл для правильного отображения товаров и счетчика

Tags: php, sql

Есть каталог с товарами, в котором отображаются различные поля из бд и также есть таймер отсчета до конца ставки.
Куда и какой цикл вставить,чтобы все корректно отображалось

```
<? while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
      {?>
      <img src="<?print $row["tov_image"];?>" width="300px" height="200px">
      <p><? print $row["tov_nazv"]?></p>
      <p><? print $row["start_price"]?></p>
      <p><? print $row["this_price"]?></p>

      <?  $date = strtotime($row['finish_time']);
          $remaining = $date - strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));?>
      <p id="countdown"></p>

      <p><button onclick="document.getElementById('id04').style.display='block'">Сделать ставку</button></p>
        <div id="id04" class="modal">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id04').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <form class="modal-content animate" action="bid.php" method="post">
          <div class="container">
            <label><b>Текущая цена</b></label>
            <input type="text" value="<?print $row["this_price"]?>" name="this_price" required>
            <label><b>Ваша ставка</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Введите цену" pattern="^[0-9 ]+$" name="this_price" required>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id04').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Отмена</button>
            <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">ОК</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>

      <?}?>
  </div>
```

У меня несколько товаров на одной странице,но таймер отображается только для первого и полностью поломан,если отображать один товар(допустим if вместо while),то все ок.[image: while[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cebqP.jpg)

сам скрипт

```
<script>
  var initialTime = <? echo $remaining; ?>;
  var seconds = initialTime ;
  function timer() {
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds /24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "minutes " + remainingSeconds+ "seconds";
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Время вышло";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

Comment: в цикле у вас высчитывается время, но потом не используется. Я преполагаю что оно используется дальше (переменная $remaining) в js. Не достаточно кода.

Comment: @JurijJazdanov добавил код

Answer (score 0):

У вас все элементы с одинаковыми id, не надо так. Делайте селектор по классу и применяйте ваш счетчик в цикле ко всем элементам, например с jquery

```
$(".countdown").each(function() {
```

Или как вам удобно.